# awk: print only one value to extracted text

Tags: awk

I need print only one value to extracted test with awk. I use aws-cli command to retrieve id of instance and connect to ssh, but when instance scale with autoscaling i have 2 id in same line:
Output of command `as-describe-auto-scaling-groups mygroup` is

`AUTO-SCALING-GROUP mygroup myistance_prod eu-west-1a,eu-west-1b,eu-west-1c ELB-autoscaling 1 5 1 Default INSTANCE i-caf3xxxx i-thc8xxxx eu-west-1a InService Healthy myistance_prod TAG auto-scaling-group Cost centre true`

With awk i extract the id's:

```
as-describe-auto-scaling-groups mygroup | grep "INSTANCE" | awk '{print $2}'`
```

This line print the ID of instance in the autoscaling group:

```
i-caf3xxxx i-thc8xxxx
```

i need only first value, it's possible?

Comment: try to improve the explanation. What is the output of `as-describe-auto-scaling-groups mygroup`? What is the current output? What is the desired one in all cases? Currently it is a bit unclear. Also, note that piping grep and then awk is not necessary: `awk '/INSTANCE/ {print $2}'` is enough.

Comment: output is: `AUTO-SCALING-GROUP mygroup myistance_prod eu-west-1a,eu-west-1b,eu-west-1c ELB-autoscaling 1 5 1 Default INSTANCE i-caf3xxxx i-thc8xxxx eu-west-1a InService Healthy myistance_prod TAG auto-scaling-group Cost centre true`. Under `INSTANCE` i have 2 id's, i need print only the first

Comment: Please [edit] your question to see this info. In comments it is not readable enough to be representative.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to print this: i-caf3xxxx, instead of the whole value.

The essence of your awk statement is

```
{split($2,a, " "); print a[1];}
```

These statements take $2 and split it at the space, putting the results in array a. You then print the first element in the array.